# Algorithm complexity analysis C++

Tags: loops, c++11, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

What if i have a loop like this

```
for( int i=2 ; i<n ; i=i*i ){ 
    .
    .
}
```

what the complexity of such a loop would be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the *j*th iteration, *i* is 2<sup>2<sup>*j*</sup></sup>, so there are O(log log n) iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan has already answered this question. This is just to explain how on the jth iteration, i is 2<sup>2<sup>*j*</sup></sup>

```
2         = 2^1 //iteration 0
2 * 2     = 2^2 //iteration 1
2^2 * 2^2 = 2^4 //iteration 2
2^4 * 2^4 = 2^8 //iteration 3
2^8 * 2^8 = 2^16 //iteration 4
```

y = 2<sup>2<sup>*j*</sup></sup>

log y = 2<sup>*j*</sup>

log (log y) = j

Thus, the total number of iterations is **log (log y)**

Answer (score 0):

If the loop starts at 0, which was the OP's initial question:

It will be an infinite loop unless n<=0. `i` starts at 0, and 0*0=0. If n<=0, the loop will not execute because the condition `i<n` would not be met upon loop entry.

Comment: sorry , i made a mistake , i mean

Answer (score 0):

The loop will execute as long as:

```
22iteration - 1 < n
```

or:

```
iteration < log2(log2(n)) + 1
```

thus the will be exactly:

```
ceil(log2(log2(n)))
```

iterations. (Assuming n > sqrt(2) and counting iterations from 1.)